# JQuery DataTable: Set colspan of column title dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Unlike in the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html) provided by documentation, I want to make column title span dynamically.

I have generated sample `data`

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        var dataRow = [];
        dataRow.push ("10" + (i + 1));
        dataRow.push ("A");
        for (var k = 0; k < 8; ++k) {
            dataRow.push ("B");
            dataRow.push ("test");
        }
        data.push (dataRow);
    }
}
```

tried to generate header via `columnDefs`

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        title: "title",
        targets: [0, 1]
    }
];

for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    columnDefs.push ({
        title: "data" + i,
        targets: [(i + 1) * 2, (i + 1) * 2 + 1]
    });
}
```

and generated table

```
$("#table").DataTable({
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    data: data,
    rowsGroup: [
        0
    ],
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    fixedHeader: true,
    fixedColumns: {
        leftColumns: 2
    },
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: "200px",
    scrolLCollapse: true,
    info: false,
    ordering: false
});
```

but table duplicated title on each column assigned by `targets` field. Is there any way I can merge them (effectively making `th`s have `colspan` of 2)?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aLqz181m/2/)

Comment: I've tried using jQuery, but it just weirds out. I was using this: `$("#table thead th:first-child").attr('colspan',2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the DataTable `colspan` work requires a second header row, one that has a single header cell for each column.

Quote from https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html:

> Note that each column must have at least one unique cell (i.e. a cell without colspan) so DataTables can use that cell to detect the column and use it to apply ordering.

But to answer your question on how to add headers with `colspan` dynamically, you can do the following:

```
var headers = '<thead><tr><th colspan="2">Title</th><th colspan="2">1</th><th colspan="2">2</th><th colspan="2">3</th><th colspan="2">4</th><th colspan="2">5</th><th colspan="2">6</th><th colspan="2">7</th><th colspan="2">8</th></tr>';
headers += '<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead>';

$("#table").append(headers);

$("#table").DataTable({...});
```

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pn4aLmpb/1/

To give it the correct appearance you may be able to apply a height of 0 to this second row. Note that `display:none` won't work as the headers will no longer align with the row data. This is because behind the scenes DataTable cleverly generates several overlapping HTML tables to simulate the effects of frozen rows, columns and headings, so there is a distinct disconnect between the column data and the column headings.

Comment: I'll add that the author of DataTables has stated that there is no API way to span columns (in the header) and that it should be done through Javascript.